# TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer 4

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create sudoku, but I'm getting this error. I think it's because of the `range` line; maybe I'm doing it wrong, but `range(int(numb/numb+3))` doesn't really work either. Thanks for the help.

```
File "D:\Games\Python\sudokuV2Test2.py", line 83, in estDansSousMatrice
    for i in range(bl, bl+3):
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"
```

This is the code:

```
def estDansSousMatrice(grille,l,c,v):
    bc=(c/3)*3
    bl=(l/3)*3

    for i in range(bl, bl+3):
        for j in range(bc,bc+3):
            if grille[i][j]==v:
                return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your previously dividing `bc` and `bl` and then multiplying by 3, say we input `c = 3` and `l = 3` the outcomes for both of those would be `3.0`
instead do `for i in range(int(bl),int(bl)+3):` and `for j in range(int(bc),int(bc)+3):`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, you can sidestep the converting back to `int` by never making them floats in the first place. The `//` operator performs integer division, truncating the result. This lets you keep almost all of your original code.

```
def estDansSousMatrice(grille,l,c,v):
    bc=(c//3)*3  # Different
    bl=(l//3)*3  # Different

    for i in range(bl, bl+3):
        for j in range(bc,bc+3):
            if grille[i][j]==v:
                return True
    return False
```